# Maintaing a new type of user, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently in my rails application i have used devise to generate "user" model that has email and password. This model has one to one relationship with another model "profileAboutuser" that has description about the user like name,address,etc. Whenever a new user signs up, corresponding table is created.

```
 has_one :profile_user, dependent: :destroy
 after_create :build_profile_user
```

My application also requires another kind of user "theExpert". "theExpert" is a user that answers to any users query. "theExpert" can only be created by **approval of developer,admin**. A typical user **cannot** be "theExpert". Lets the expert model be "profileExpert" which describes various expert information.

How do i maintain "theExpert".

Do i create a new devise model for "theExpert", though this means create a seperate login form which is not desirable.

Or Should i add new boolean field to profileUser "is_expert" that is set false by default. And a developer,admin can set this value to true, when required.

Or should i change my existing code to support polymorphic associations. A user can either be expert or typical user.

**Edit-**
Do I need to choose between, if a user is Expert or typical. Can i not add an extra profileExpert connection to a typical user when required?

Answer (score 2):

Better you should implement single table inheritance.

[image]

Checkout the following link to learn  how to implement single table inheritance.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

If you have too many unique fields on each of the table, then don't implement STI. create a seperate model instead.

Comment: I read that single table inhertiance is not suitable when both models have many unique fields

Comment: That's correct. Anyway both the users(Expert and profile users) are going to have the common user attributes right?

Comment: expert will need all of the user attributes, but need many extra attributes of its own

Comment: Then create a sepeate model. checkout my updated answer

Comment: is it ok to have a seperate login forms , one for user and one for expert. I dont see any other sites following such a approach?

Comment: You can have a common login also. You have to write a controller that handles all types of login

Comment: can you direct me to some kind of tutorial? How can one controller handle two devise logins?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78898/discussion-between-kamesh-and-codervishal).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with STI(Single table inheritance). Due to which you will not need to create new model for Expert user

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 end

 class Expert < User
 end
```

So when you do Expert.create, It will automatically set type column in user to expert.

This way in future if you want to add any new type of user just inherit User same as Expert.

But if you have unique fields in both tables then dont go with STI.In that case better create new model instead.